# Nexus to Cache Artifacts using Ivy

Tags: ant, ivy, nexus

Ok; my first stackoverflow question.

I have been trying to use our local Nexus to download artifacts from and to retrieve those artifacts automatically from an outer repositories in case they don't exist. and ***CACHE*** them in the way.

I am using Ant and Ivy to handle the dependency.

More or less the question is similar to this question:
[Ivy via Nexus proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033859/ivy-via-nexus-proxy)
The ultimate answer to my understanding did enable the use of nexus as a repository but it didn't cache (at least not for me).

I have seen lots of material hovering around the subject but nothing of the exact nature (and sadly I couldn't figure it out).

So let me wrap it up.
I am using the local nexus repository using a url resolver, because we should use a URL if we need to publish (read that somewhere):

```
<chain name="deploy-chain">
    <url
        name="nexus"
        m2compatible="true"
    >
        <artifact pattern="${nexus.host}/${nexus.pattern}" />
        <ivy pattern="${nexus.host}/${nexus.ivy.pattern}" />
    </url>

    <ibiblio
        name="maven.public"
        m2compatible="true"
    />
</chain>
```

The ivy.xml and build.xml are very standard.

So, is it possible to do this using Ivy or is this a nexus issue?

Is it a good practice to publish the artifacts (designated ant target) to Nexus after I retrieve the artifacts in my cache or local repository? (it seems like a really bad practice, but the only option is always a great option)

Is this a misuse of the tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ibiblio](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/resolver/ibiblio.html) resolver is the best way to configure a Maven repository.

The following **ivysettings.xml** file configures ivy to pull it's dependencies Nexus.

```
<ivysettings>
    <settings defaultResolver="central-proxy"/>
    <resolvers>
        <ibiblio name="central-proxy" m2compatible="true" root="http://mynexushost/nexus/content/repositories/central/"/>
        <ibiblio name="release-repo"  m2compatible="true" root="http://mynexushost/nexus/content/repositories/releases/"/>
    </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

The "central-proxy" resolver is configured to pull content from the default Maven Central proxy repository that comes by default in Nexus.

The "release-repo" resolver can be used when publishing content to the Nexus release repository.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark. It worked.
The caching took place, even though I tried lots of other things like URL resolver, or changing the shared cache and such but nothing seemed to work.
Thanks again.